# Call popup not appearing in iOS flutter_callkit_incoming

Tags: flutter, voip

We are using flutter_callkit_incoming for our call processing but after implementation of APN for call notification calls seems to be coming in foreground but shows a small icon on top left and users can't interact with the call.

[Image with phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpCaH.jpg)

I followed all the steps mentioned in this documentation by the author [here](https://github.com/hiennguyen92/flutter_callkit_incoming/blob/master/PUSHKIT.md).
It works perfectly fine in iOS but not working in iPhone.

Comment: The first thing to check is whether you have correctly set up the package according to the instructions. This includes setting up the necessary permissions in your ```Info.plist``` file for iOS, as well as correctly implementing the package's methods in your code.